# integer has been converted to string, but still recognized as int

Tags: python-3.x

```
print("Hello World!")
print("What's your name?") # ask for their name
myName = input()
print("Nice to meet you" + myName)
print("The length of your name is: ")
print(len(myName))
print("How old are you") # ask for their age
myAge = input()
print("you will be " + str(myAge + 1) + " in a year")
```

The last line, I thought I have converted number (myAge + 1) to a string, but why it's still recognized as a integer?

Comment: According to [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input), `input` returns a string.

Comment: Why do you think it is recognized as an integer? `myAge` is a string!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does this error happen? TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979824/why-does-this-error-happen-typeerror-can-only-concatenate-str-not-int-to-s)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're getting the following error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

This doesn't mean that the `str(myAge + 1)` is an int, it means that myAge is a str, and 1 is an int. Fix it by replacing it with the following.

```
print("you will be " + str(int(myAge) + 1) + " in a year")
```

Comment: That answers my question. Thank you.